# Partition Pruning in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Postgres provides a way to disable partition pruning using set option-

```
set enable_partition_pruning = off
```

Is there a use case for disabling partition pruning ? I find it always advantageous to have the partition pruning. Can't understand why this is made a settable option.

Comment: There is literally a use case in the official Postgres docs on Partition Pruning.

Answer (score 1):

First, most of the `enable_*` parameters are not designed to be changed permanently, they are intended to be used in experiments like “how much faster would query planning be if it didn't check for partitions to prune?”.

A possible use case for disabling the parameter permanently would be if you are using partitioning, but you know that none of your queries can benefit from partition pruning. Then not trying will save time and effort for the optimizer.

Comment: Did you mean to say possible use case for disabling the parameter permanently would be if you are NOT using partitioning?

Comment: No - if you are using partitioning, but any cycle expended on partition pruning would be wasted.